# I am trying to develop a Complex number calculator.

Tags: c++, constructor, calculator

Constructor must be defining the following objects and printing them:

```
CComplex c1;
CComplex c2(1,3);
CComplex c3(4);
CComplex c4(c3);
```

To Implement overloaded operators for the +, -, *and /operation, supporting operations 
between 2 complex numbers as well as operations between a float and a complex number.

But the objects are giving error if declared with only one parameter. Checked out an example of FOO.h on the community and tried implementing but did not work out.

Comment: This "question" is an incomprehensible mess.

Comment: Please post your code and the messages you're getting from the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is truly to have a complex number calculator, and not to complete a school assignment or other exercise with some arbitrary restrictions, then you should use [`std::complex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex) and do not reinvent the wheel.

For what it's worth, the constructor of `std::complex` takes two arguments, both with default values. Not mentioning templates, `std::complex< double >` effectively explicitly defines one constructor:

```
complex( double real = 0, double imaginary = 0 );
```

Implementing this should gain the functionality mentioned in the question.